# How to eliminate extra Drupal Logout Link

Tags: users

[image]

Hi, there, I am working with Organic Groups on an existing drupal 7 site. For some reason, there are three log out links. I checked with User Menu, which is not even enabled in this site. How can I find out why there are three log out links?

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Devel Themer (https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer). That works kinda like a firebug/backtrace for themeing, and it should point you to where those links are coming from. Keep in mind Themer is a bit buggy, and can cause some issues, so you might want to switch it off when your done, but it should help you diagnose your problem.